# How to solve a non-linear equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

We want to solve the equation $Y''=YY'$. We know that the solution is $Y=B\dfrac{1-De^{Bx}}{1+De^{Bx}}$ but we don't know how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You integrate once and get three cases

1. $Y'=\frac12(Y^2+B^2)$, $B>0$,
2. $Y'=\frac12 Y^2 $,
3. $Y'=\frac12(Y^2-B^2)$, $B>0$,

which are all standard ODE that can be solved 1.) via the arcus tangent and 2.) via separation of variables, which in 3.) then also requires a partial fraction decomposition (or the area tangent hyp., that is, the inverse hyperbolic tangent).

---

One could also classify these resulting ODE as Riccati equations and apply the typical substitution $Y=-\frac{2U'}{U}$ to get $Y'=-\frac{2U''}{U}+\frac12Y^2$, resulting in
$$
-\frac{2U''}{U}=Y'-\frac12Y^2=\frac12C\implies U''+\frac{C}4U=0,
$$
$C=0$ or $C=\pm B^2$, which is again a standard class of ODE with trigonometric or hyperbolic solutions.

Comment: We have thought about what you say but we still don't achieve the exactly solution that we are looking for

Comment: It is case 3. Separation gives $\frac{2BY'}{Y^2-B^2}=B$, after using $2B=(Y+B)-(Y-B)$ and integration $\ln|Y-B|-\ln|Y+B|=Bx+d$, and then solve $\frac{Y-B}{Y+B}=-De^{Bx}$ for $Y$. (The sign of $D$ is chosen so that your solution formula results.)